# Devise Mailer EOF 500 status error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I'm new to ActionMailer, but I've also read the documentation on it. I am just not sure how Devise is handling it. I'm using Rails 5.1, yet I can't get the Devise mailer to work in development.

I get the following error when I try get the reset password email in development:

```
EOFError in Devise::PasswordsController#create
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"token info",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"user@email.com"},
 "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
```

In the server log:

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-26 17:18:09 -0400
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token", "user"=>{"email"=>"user@email.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "user@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["reset_password_token", "token"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_token" = $1, "reset_password_sent_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["reset_password_token", "token"], ["reset_password_sent_at", "2018-07-26 21:18:10.075033"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-26 21:18:10.076032"], ["id", 2]]
   (2.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
  Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb (1.1ms)
Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 452.1ms

Sent mail to user@email.com (30027.6ms)
Date: Thu, 26 Jul 2018 17:18:11 -0400
To: user@email.com
Message-ID: <my system>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8

... the view...

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31449ms (ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)

EOFError (end of file reached):
```

I've set up my config/environments/development.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # Using MailCatcher server -- running @ 1080
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: "localhost", port: 1080 }
```

I have the MailCatcher server running. When I set 'raise_deliver_errors' = false, I get a flash saying the message is sent, but MailCatcher never receives anything.

I'm a little confused, every single thing I've researched says I only need to do this to make it work -- I don't want to play with the Devise Controllers if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was just turn this line of code from

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

into

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

The views came up in the log, and when I configured Sendgrid on production the emails were sent properly.

Edit: this is in the `development.rb` file